# Style file elsarticle-num-names can't be opened

Tags: bibtex, elsarticle

I am compiling my `.tex` document with TexMaker and the bib style is

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names.bst}
```

and I get the following error which I don't know what to do with

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6600 64-bit) The top-level
>   auxiliary file: test.aux I couldn't open style file
>   elsarticle-num-names.bst.bst ---line 269 of file test.aux :
>   \bibstyle{elsarticle-num-names.bst : } I'm skipping whatever remains
>   of this command I found no style file---while reading file
>   test.aux (There were 2 error messages)

Can someone offer suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The `\bibliographystyle` already includes the .bst extension, you don't have to inform it.

Notice the double extension in the error:

> couldn't open style file elsarticle-num-names.bst.bst

Use only:

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
```

Comment: ohh I guess I should take a break, I was so blind to not to see this. Thanks @Phelype Oleinik

Comment: @Noname That's always a good idea :) You're welcome!